# Is there any scenario in which we can use the present tense after "I wish..."?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is the following sentence correct?

"I really wish I don't see her again."

Comment: That's not _wish_; that's _hope_. Different verb, different grammar, different presuppositions.

Comment: One could say "I wish I was rich" - which would refer to the present. I'm not clear myself as to why we do not use the present tense, but I am certain @JohnLawler can tell us. It is a bit like the conditional "If I was rich".

Comment: Since it's the present when you speak, using past is a signal.that you're only kidding. _Wish_ and one sense of _if_ are irrealis -- they presuppose that something is false and go from there.

Comment: I wish I may, I wish I might have the wish I wish tonight.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks John. I did discover [this site describing the "unreal past"](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/unreal-past/) which may help non-native speakers. But it is not unique to English, of course. It exists in French and presumably other European languages - *Si j'étais riche*.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any situations where that construction would be acceptable. The closest thing I can think of would be using an infinitive after "I wish":

> I wish never **to see** her again.